# Storing a Bitmap resource in a static variable

Tags: java, android

I have a view which displays a small bitmap, and this is used in many places in my application (especially list views). I'm currently loading this bitmap each time an instance of that view is created using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, id)`. I realized that I can improve performance by loading that bitmap once into a static variable (so that all instances of the view reuse it) and that did indeed save about 2-4 ms per view instance. My question, does using a static variable in this way cause any type of memory leak in Android? I'm worried because I haven't found any other example that uses a static variable to store a bitmap like this.

**Follow up question:** [How to keep a Bitmap in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824004/how-to-keep-a-bitmap-in-memory)

Comment: quoting romain guy "When a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the drawable. In the code snippet above, this means the drawable has a reference to the TextView which itself has a reference to the activity (the Context) which in turns has references to pretty much anything (depending on your code.)"...so keeping it in static is going to cause a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks @0cool, I have seen that post but I'm not sure that a  `android.graphics.Bitmap` (not `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`) is also a `Drawable`. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: Hi, @AbdullahJibaly Do we need to import or extend something before using Bitmap? As I am doing `Bitmap device;` and my IDE is giving an error that _Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type_. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping bitmap objects as static may cause potential memory leaks, see official documents at
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thanks @calvin, I didn't realize a `Bitmap` is a `Drawable` since there doesn't seem to be any relation in the class hierarchy. Just to be clear I'm using a `android.graphics.Bitmap` not a `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`. If the same caveat applies, what is the most straight-forward solution to this problem?

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824004/how-to-keep-a-bitmap-in-memory

Comment: A Bitmap is *not* a drawable, so this answer is just wrong, or at least is not supported by the content of the link.